# Error, C# NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

[image: Aqui esta una imagen del codigo y el error que me lanza]Como puedo resolver este problema de NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code, donde tengo insertada una tabla y me dice que el valor que me retorna es nulo?

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


    /// <summary>
    ///Clase Cliente
    /// </summary>
    public class clscliente: clsconexion
    {

        string tabla = "Clientes"; /

/

    Nombre de mi tabla
        protected string Nombre, Direccion, Telefono;
        protected int idCliente;
        public clscliente(int idCliente, string Nombre, string Direccion, string Telefono)
        {
    this.idcliente = idcliente;
    this.Nombre = Nombre;
    this.Direccion = Direccion;
    this.Telefono = Telefono;

}

//metodos para establecer y recuperar datos
public int idcliente {
    set { idCliente = value; }
    get { return idCliente; }
}
public string nombre{
    set { Nombre = value; }
    get { return Nombre; }
}
public string direccion
{
    set { Direccion = value; }
    get { return Direccion; }
}
public string telefono
{
    set { Telefono = value; }
    get { return Telefono; }
}
//metodo agregar
public void agregar() {
    conectar(tabla);
    DataRow fila;
    fila = Data.Tables["tabla"].NewRow(); 
    fila["idCliente"] = idcliente;
    fila["Nombre"] = Nombre;
    fila["Direccion"] = Direccion;
    fila["Telefono"] = Telefono;

    Data.Tables[tabla].Rows.Add(fila);
    AdaptadorDatos.Update(Data, tabla);


    }
}
```

Comment: Comprueba que exista una tabla llamada "Tabla"

Answer (score 0):

esa excepción se produce cuando se accede a un objeto no inicializado, es decir, que apunta a `null`. Pon un punto de ruptura en esa linea y verifica que tanto `Data` como `Data.Tables["tabla"]` no sean `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Para que uses **.NewRow()** lo primero que debes tener es un objeto del tipo `DataTable` con sus columnas definidas: mira en [DataTable.NewRow Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx); allí veras que crean el objeto, le agregan columnas y *solicitan* nueva fila.